# is there delete orphen in JPA

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa-2.0

I have group and user where group must have an owner otherwise he couldn't exist 
in hibernate in order to achieve this outcome I do :

```
@ManyToOne
@org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN
private User owner;
```

(inside my group entity)

my question is how to do it when my all project configuration is JPA 2.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the problem , not the ideal way but it does the work :

(inside group)

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,optional=false)
private User owner;
```

even thought when deleting the user the group is not deleted but this is for the logic of the application to deduce...